# Middleware Or Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a scenario where I want to check a feature flag per request. The way I have implemented this so far is I use middleware..

```
public class SalesFeatureMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IFeatureFlagRequestContext _featureFlagRequestContext;

    public SalesFeatureMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        IFeatureFlagRequestContext featureFlagRequestContext)
    {
        _next = next;
        _featureFlagRequestContext = featureFlagRequestContext;
    }
    
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var featureEnabled = _featureFlagRequestContext.GetValue("sale-flag");
        context.Features.Set(SalesFeature.Create(featureEnabled));
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

In my startup (`ConfigureServices()`), I use the following to inject this instance so I can use it later..

```
        services.AddScoped(sp =>
        {
            var ctx = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var feature = ctx.HttpContext.Features.Get<SalesFeature>();
            return feature ?? SalesFeature.Default();   
        });
```

The idea is this is done once (per request), check status of the feature flag which can be changed during the running of the app as this is controlled using another service (Launch Darkly). I guess my question is, is this better suited to using a filter instead?

Comment: You don't need any middleware for this...

Comment: Last time I did research in this area, "Filters" only applied to Controller Actions, so if you have a request that was handled by some endpoint handler _other_ than a `ControllerBase` action method then no Filters would be invoked. HTH.

Comment: When you say no middleware why not? It's a cross cutting concern meaning the flag is used in multiple places so making the call once is surely better than having it everywhere?

Comment: I guess with filters you can't inject an instance of something like I can do here using a mix of middleware and startup? My understanding is that the instance of SalesFeature will change per request.